# How do I split this into maybe 2 or 3 functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just wondering how do I split this into different functions say like maybe 2 or 3 functions? I'm not that good with passing parameters with functions yet. Would you recommend doing that or should I keep it the way it is in one function since it's a while loop? By the way it's for a beginner programming class so that's why its pretty long.

```
def sumOfDoublePlace(userChoice):
    lenChecker = len(str(userChoice))
    counter = 0
    sumNumber = 0
    userChoice = int(userChoice)
    while counter < lenChecker-1:
        counter += 1
        endDigit, userChoice = divmod(userChoice, 10)

        if counter % 2 == 0:
            evenNumber = endDigit * 2

            if evenNumber < 10:
                sumNumber = sumNumber + evenNumber

            else:
                oddDigit = endDigit % 10
                firstDigit = endDigit // 10
                oddSum = oddDigit + firstDigit
                sumNumber = sumNumber + oddSum
        else:
            sumNumber = sumNumber + endDigit

    if sumNumber % 10 == 0:
        print('This card is valid')
    else:
        print('This card is invalid')
```

Comment: What is being passed in? What is the intent of this function?

Comment: the function pretty much gets the userinput (which in this case is a 13-16 digit credit card number and this function does the algorithm to verify if it's a valid credit card number. The userChoice is the where the user input is stored

Comment: ... and what constitutes "valid"?  This appears to be the odd/even digit checksum algorithm from Ye Olde Days; what sub-functions do you imagine make sense?

Comment: Also, you haven't bothered to use your **lenChecker** value.  You might want to finish that part of the assignment.

Comment: This is for an intro to programming class so everything is very basic so far, I haven't learned a lot of like complicated functions or terms yet other than these and I did use lenChecker on the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, I think this should be a single routine.  However, you are taking a somewhat tortuous path to the solution.  You're doing a *lot* of work to pull digits out of the integer version of the card number, when they're perfectly accessible in the original text.

Here's a start on accessing the string positions you need:

```
def isValidCardNumber(cardNumber):
    num_len = len(cardNumber)
    last  = int(cardNumber[-1])  # grab the last digit; convert to integer
    odds  = cardNumber[0:-1:2]   # positions 0, 2, 4, ... last-1
    evens = cardNumber[1:-1:2]   # positions 1, 3, 5, ... last-1

    # For each list of digits, make a list of their integer equivalents.
    #     ... and immediately take the sum of those integers.
    odd_sum  = sum([int(digit) for digit in odds])
    even_sum = sum([int(digit) for digit in evens])
```

I leave the rest of this to you.  :-)

Comment: THAT'S WHAT I'VE BEEN TRYING TO DO WITH THE INPUT! haha I just had trouble knowing how to change them into integers coming from strings but I originally had that idea just didn't know how to expand it since we only started talking about strings 2 classes ago but thank you so much!

Comment: +1 for understanding the behavior of original code. I was unable to grasp what the original code mentioned in the question was doing.

Comment: @anonymous: One of the advantages of having taught programming ... :-)